# SQLite query SELECT login, password FROM user WHERE login = 'login' returns wrong result

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a "user" table with two entries.

```
id | login | password
0  | unauthorized user | pas
1  | login | hash
```

For some reason, the query `"SELECT login, password FROM user WHERE login = 'login'"` returns two records.
Any help, please.

Comment: My wild guess is that login is not quoted properly so  login = login is basically comparing column with itself which is always true. Insert user with name that is not equal to any column name (e.g. foo) and try your query on that. Also paste query as-is here (code -formatted). That will help with triage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your query is actually using double-quotes for your string `'login'` instead of single-quotes, i.e. that your query *actually* looks like this:

```
SELECT login, password FROM user WHERE login = "login"
```

This will not work as-intended [because SQLite follows the ISO SQL specification which actually states that double-quotes are used to delimit literal object identifiers](https://blog.christosoft.de/2012/10/sqlite-escaping-table-acolumn-names/). Other RDBMS frequently deviate from this rule (e.g. MySQL uses `` `name` `` backticks, T-SQL for Sybase and MS SQL Server uses square-brackets `[name]`, etc).

Change your query to ensure you're using single-quotes for the value, or better yet, use parameterised queries (you'll need to check with your SQLite library's API documentation on how to do this, as you haven't told us what library and language you're using):

```
SELECT login, password FROM user WHERE login = 'login'
```

Or, to be clear:

```
SELECT "login", "password" FROM "user" WHERE "login" = 'login'
```

---

I note that because SQLite is in-proc and does not have built-in authentication or authorization (i.e. it has no access-controls) [it does not have `USER`, `LOGIN` and `PASSWORD` as reserved keywords](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) - but I feel it's important to write portable SQL because it's almost inevitable that a growing project will move from SQLite to a client/server RDBMS which *will* have those keywords and then your queries *will* break with a syntax error.

Also, I trust you aren't actually storing unencrypted (or even reversibly-encrypted) passwords in that table. If you are storing hashed passwords then you should also store a salt value (which *may* be contained within the stored hash value if you're using a scheme like `bcrypt`).

Comment: Yes, it really was in quotes.
Thank you very much

Comment: @MyNick Single quotes or double-quotes though?

Comment: Yes, single quotes